# How do I rotate the camera during Story Mode in Super Bomberman R?

Tags: super-bomberman-r

While playing Story Mode in *Super Bomberman R*, I managed to accidentally rotate the camera slightly to the right. The camera rotation persisted between levels, and I’m not sure how to turn it back.

How do you rotate the camera during Story Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera control is limited to three preset angles in Story Mode: left, center, and right.

To change camera angles during Story Mode:

- **Paired Joycons**: Hold L or R
- **Single Joycon**: Hold SL or SR
- **Pro Controller**: Hold L or R